# How to Sort/ Limit the API call for Groups for member list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-group

1. I see that we can only get 500 members of a group using the graph API.
   and the doc says these are "the first 500 members",

Are these sorted by date signed up, or latest 500?

Is there any way I can further limit these to signed up in the last 24 hours/ 1 week?

2. Is the 500 limit there in using FQL also? (the docs don't specify that )

Is there any way I can further limit these to signed up in the last 24 hours/ 1 week using FQL?

Answer (score 0):

> i see that we can only get 500 members of a group using the graph API. and the doc says these are "the first 500 members",
>
> are these sorted by date signed up, or latest 500,???

I’d say by date of joining the group, because otherwise calling them the “first” 500 would make little sense.

> Is the 500 limit there in using FQL also? (the docs dont specify that )

From my tests there seems to be no such limit on the `group_member` table (just tried it for the FB developer group using Grapf API explorer, and my browser froze for about a minute loading the data).

> is there any way i can further limit these to signed up in the last 24 hours/ 1 week using FQL?

No, there is no such info as signup date in the FQL table.

Comment: Been playing with FQl and it seems it only gives me back something like 4800 ~ 4900 members, pinging to a group which says 6670 members? why this limit? is this a bug?

Comment: I think the (implicit) default `limit` parameter value is 5000. Try explicitly setting a higher value.

Comment: URL=fql.query?query=select+gid%2C+uid+from+group_member+where+gid+%3D+[GROUP_ID]+order+by+uid+limit+0%2C+1500&access_token=
COUNT=1500

URL=fql.query?query=select+gid%2C+uid+from+group_member+where+gid+%3D+[GROUP_ID]+order+by+uid+limit+1500%2C+1500&access_token=
COUNT=1500

URL=fql.query?query=select+gid%2C+uid+from+group_member+where+gid+%3D+[GROUP_ID]+order+by+uid+limit+3000%2C+1500&access_token=
COUNT=1500

URL=fql.query?query=select+gid%2C+uid+from+group_member+where+gid+%3D+[GROUP_ID]+order+by+uid+limit+4500%2C+1500&access_token=
COUNT=412

END

using limit, records 4912; group has 6624

Comment: anyone?

am using FQl and limiting results to 1500 per query, and am just getting 4912 records, where the group as 6642 members.

is there a limit to query the group_member table?